# Installing Python Packages(numpy,scipy,statsmodels,etc..) on an offline Windows machine

Tags: windows, python-3.x, installation, package, offline

I have successfully installed ***`python 3.5`*** on the machine but I need certain packages like *`numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas`, `statsmodels`*, etc installed on it too.

The computer is not connected to the Internet but has a USB port, so is there a way to get packages like the ones mentioned above along with their necessary dependencies(everything should be fully functional) ***on a pen drive and install them on the windows computer?***

I found something that can be done on an [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) machine where I get the packages and their dependencies from another computer and install them on the offline machine which actually worked well [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/165488).

Is there a similar ***alternative on Windows***?

Answer (score 3):

For anybody who comes this way in desperation, I got my problem solved with this [page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) maintained by Christian Gohlke. This page is completely self-sufficient in serving your needs of most of the popular Python packages for offline installation on Windows, it suggests the required dependencies and provides links to them in case they're not on the site.
Once you place the folder of the packages(.whl files) and the dependencies on the desktop (or elsewhere) on the offline computer, navigate to the folder within the command prompt and then type-

```
pip install file-name.whl
```

as suggested [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels), and you'll be good to go!

Comment: Nowadays you'll find Windows wheels for many packages on PyPI, including numpy and pandas, but AFAIK *Christoph* is the only one distributing a scipy wheel. Plus his builds use Intel's MKL for optimized BLAS/LAPACK routines.

Comment: Ha! that helped me zero.